# How to use Date/Time functions with JSONB values?

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I am usually using this syntax to group by day:

```
SELECT date_trunc('day', loggedin) AS "Day" , count(*) AS "No. of users"
FROM logins
WHERE created > now() - interval '3 months' 
GROUP BY 1 
ORDER BY 1;
```

Now my Date-value is inside a JSONB column called `extras`.

```
SELECT date_trunc('day', "extras"->>'sent') AS date , count(*) AS "value"
FROM "document"
GROUP BY 1 
ORDER BY 1;
```

This gives this error:

> ERROR:  function date_trunc(unknown, text) does not exist LINE 1:
>   SELECT date_trunc('day', "extras"->>'sent') AS date , count(...
>                  ^ HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Is there a way to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cast the text of `extras->>'sent'` to `date`:

```
SELECT date_trunc('day', ("extras"->>'sent')::date) AS date , count(*) AS "value"
FROM "document"
GROUP BY 1 
ORDER BY 1;
```

Comment: Because (1) JSON doesn't support date or time types and (2) `->>` returns `text` anyway.